# Why does ASP.NET Core MVC not validate password, but validates e-mail?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core-mvc

My code on the server-side doesn't indeed validate the e-mail field, but I cannot understand, why it doesn't validate it for the password.

Here is my markup in the `.cshtml` file:

```
<label asp-for="Email"></label>
<input asp-for="Email" />
<span asp-validation-for="Email"></span>
<br />

<label asp-for="Password"></label>
<input asp-for="Password" />
<span asp-validation-for="Password"></span>
<br />
```

This is my code for the model class:

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string? Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string? Email { get; set; }
```

This is how I set the conditions for password in the `Program.cs` file:

```
builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(o => {
    o.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
    o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    o.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    o.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    o.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
});
```

I've also tried to use the `[StringLength]` data annotation, but it didn't work either.

and lastly the fragment responsible for using the Password:

```
com.CommandText = "Insert into users (name, email, password) " +
                    "Values (@name, @email, @password);";
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", acc.Name);
                var hashedpassword = helperMethods.HashPasword(acc.Password);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", hashedpassword);

                dr.Close();
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close() ;

                return View("Views\\Account\\AccountCreated.cshtml");
            }
```

Comment: Define "not validate it". If you mean, at the point it hits the controller action, well yea naturally. Identity Options are only validating on saving. Also did you change anything on the controller action? Identity returns an `IdentityResult` object, and it's errors needs to be mapped to the `ModeState` of the action

Comment: I've added the fragment of coda that uses the Password, it seems strange to me, that it has no problem with the Email, but has problems with Password. And by Validate, i mean that for example, if you dont put @ in the email input, it will trigger an error, the same if you put no .net etc. I expected the same will happen for the Password if there wont be for example enought latters

Comment: Seems you are not using the ASP.NET Identity's methods / stores for managing users, hence. Identity providers an `IPasswordValidator` interface which has a [base implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.passwordvalidator-1?view=aspnetcore-7.0) that uses the parameters from `IdentityOptions`. If you skipp all of these by using your own code and not relying on UserManager and the build-in actions of course enothing will be validating and you have to do it yourself

Comment: So I have to dig into the Indentity methods... do you have maybe a site with simple examples?

Comment: Imho you should just use the out of the box ASP.NET Core Identity, it already offers all functions to register, login and manage basic profile information. You should only touch/extend it, when you really need something thats not possible with it out of the box . Identity is very extensible already (stores can be replaced usermanager extended and you can own provide implemnentation to the validators and you can extend the dedault  ÌdentityUser`/`IdentityRole` etc classes to add your own properties)